# css background color property

Tags: css, background

This syntax in a css background property works well:

```
 .my-element {
          background:
            linear-gradient( rgba(131,131,131,0.8), rgba(98,98,98,0.8) ),
            url('img/background.jpg')
}
```

I don't need a gradient though. I'd like the overlay to be from one color with some level of opacity. I know I could just have the starting color the same as the end color of a gradient but is it possible to replace 'linear-gradient' with just rgba color including opacity?. It does not seem to work.

EDIT: I might have not been clear in my question. What I'd like is:

```
.my-element {
              background:
                color(rgba(131,131,131,0.8),
                url('img/background.jpg')
    }
```

The above does not work. I can't use the hex notation for the color either as it does not include opacity.

Comment: Actually you used the rgba in your code. I think you should explain more about what you want.

Comment: See my edit. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possibilities.

Either consider a CSS variables to optimize the code and avoid repeating the color twice:

```css
.box {
  --c:rgba(131,131,131,0.8);
  
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(var(--c),var(--c)),
    url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/1002/800/800.jpg) center/cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Or use blending but you may not have the exact same result and you need to adjust the value of the blending based on the color used:

```css
.box {
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background:
    url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/1002/800/800.jpg) center/cover,
    rgba(131,131,131,0.8);
  background-blend-mode: exclusion;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an absolute overlay color:

```
<div class="my-element"><div class="overlay"></div>My element color</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.my-element {
    background: url('img/background.jpg')
    position: relavive;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.8);
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```css
.my-element {
    background: url('img/background.jpg')
    position: relavive;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.8);
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-element"><div class="overlay"></div>My element color</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. To be honest, it'll be quicker to use my original code snippet with 2 identical colors in the linear gradient statement.

Comment: Okay, that was just another way to implement your idea.

Answer (score -1):

Did you want something like that?

```css
     .my-element {
              background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5),
                url('img/background.jpg')
    }

   .my-element2 {
              background:
                linear-gradient( rgba(131,131,131,0.8), rgba(98,98,98,0.1) ),
                url('img/background.jpg')
    }
```

```html
 <div class="my-element">My element color</div>
<br>
 <div class="my-element2">My element color</div>
```